# How to make a div with glassy and semi transparent effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to give a div a glassy reflection appearance as well as a semi transparent effect. How can I combine these two effects so that the div will look like a glassy transparent gadget? Is there a way to do this?

The div's bgcolor is lightskyblue and no background image is set yet.

[image]

Comment: can you show the effect as a picture and place it in your question? So that we could help you better.

Comment: @starx that div can be turned to glassy or iced. Can't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give alpha tranparency in your background color.

For example

```
div { 
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); /* white color with 50% transparency */
}
```

In IE However, `rgba` does not works. You need to use filter.

For Example

```
div {
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#77ffffff, endColorstr=#77ffffff)"; /* For IE8 */
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#77ffffff, endColorstr=#77ffffff); /* < IE 7 */
    zoom: 1;
}
```

The color patter in both the start and end color is different than the way in `RGBA`, it user **`ARGB`** Format and all in Hex. Like in above example, following are how the values are distributed

```
77: alpha (fully transparent: 00, fully opaque: FF) 
ff: Red
ff: Green
ff: Blue
```

This method will place a transparent background on your division, but if you want the entire div to be tranparent including everything inside, then you can use `opacity` property

For example

```
div {
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5; /* This is not support in IE though, use filter if needed in IE *
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/mG9Q3/1/)

Comment: The first part of your answer is the my requirement. I need only the div background to be transparent and glasssy. Not the contents of the div. But when i tried the rgba(255,255,255,0.5) it only shows the light color. I didnt get the glassy effect. ;(

Comment: @selvin, that is an example. your background is already blue. I will create a fiddle for you.

Comment: IE 7, IE8 do not support background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

Comment: Although the transparent effect is attained to some extend, there is no glass effect

Answer (score 4):

Use the Gradient CSS properties to create a glossy effect.

For Firefox use

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, red, white, blue);
```

or

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#000,#444 45%, #777 45%, #555);
```

you can add as many colors as you want to get the right look. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient

For IE use the filter property

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/gkyg3/1/

For Transparency You need to use the RGBA background property on the container div. `background: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5)`. 64, 64, 64 are the RGB color values. and 0.5 is the opacity value. Now parent can have it's own opacity value that will not be inherited by it's children. This is fully supported by FireFox, Opera, Chrome, Safari and IE9.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/Rp5BN/

To support IE 5.5 to 8  we need to use vendor-specific CSS 'gradient filter:' So you need to add this.

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7f404040, endColorstr=#7f404040);`

Where 7f represents 127, i.e. 50% opacity and 404040 is the color.

### Check working example in IE http://jsfiddle.net/Rp5BN/2/

Answer (score 2):

it's simple only you have do is to give

```
background: rgba(256,256,256,0.5);
```

& for IE use this filter

```
{background: transparent;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FFFFFFF,endColorstr=#7FFFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FFFFFFF,endColorstr=#7FFFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */      zoom: 1;}
```

for more about color transparency in IE you have to read about hsla color:
http://greenevillage.net/csspages/hsla.aspx

**Edit**

for glassy look you can use gradient  like this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/hfTdw/5/

Answer (score 1):

For a "glassy" effect, I imagine that getting the transparency is only the first step. Personally, "glassy" will also need diagonal background artifacts (the shine and sheen of glass?) which I think will need some sort of CSS (+ making sure it doesn't buckle when resized or something).

Similarly, for "iced", I personally think you'll need a frost-like distinction, which is normally a disparate and randomly-placed/repeated image artifact.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nazmul2011/q4cLM/)

If your Browser does not support CSS3 features, you can try this. I used two DIV, one for content and another for glass effect.
I made both of their position absolute. In addition to that z-index has been used to display div one above another.

Copy the code and try it in your browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Glass Effect</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
    background-color:#AA3333;
    }
    div#content{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;

    }
    div#glass{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    background-color:#777777;
    opacity:0.20; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=20);
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
            exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
            deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    </div>
    <div id="glass">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was curious if I could do this and haven't found a good example so I'll update this for 2020.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv0no.jpg)

I did it in few ways:

diagonal transparent-opaque alternating gradient for reflection

`backdrop-filter: blur(` - not for all browsers, not firefox default in 2020

or javascript clone and `filter: blur(` effect

```js
// for only bottom div

const pre = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];
const background = document.getElementsByClassName("background")[0];
const glossy3 = document.getElementsByClassName("glossy3")[0];
// clone it
var blurit = pre.cloneNode(true);
// make it blurit class
blurit.classList.add("blurit");
// attach to background too
background.appendChild(blurit);

const redraw = async () => {
  // get dimentions of glossy3 div
  const size = glossy3.getBoundingClientRect();
  const presize = pre.getBoundingClientRect();
  const divScrolledY = background.scrollTop
 // apply these dimentions to blured background clip-path (crop)
  blurit.style.clipPath = `inset(
   ${size.top + divScrolledY}px 
    ${presize.width - size.right}px 
    ${presize.height - size.bottom - divScrolledY}px 
    ${size.left}px
    round ${ window.innerWidth * 0.02 }px
  )`;
  // 10 milisecond pause
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 10));
  // call yourself recursively via browser friendly method
  window.requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
}
/* call it once to loop forever - better than any timer */
redraw();
```

```css
.glossy1 {

   /* blurs background */
   
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px) brightness(1.1) contrast(0.9) saturate(1.1);
  

  /* uses transparent background for glare */    
  --col1: rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
  --col2: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);

  background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  var(--col1) 0%, var(--col2) 33%, var(--col1) 66%, var(--col2) 100%);

  /* background-color does nothing while gradient is up but this works for another tint: */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100vw rgba(0, 0, 150, 0.05);

  /* at same div level need this */
  z-index: 2;
}

.glossy2 {
  
  /* blue tint */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100vw rgba(20, 20, 150, 0.09);
  
  /* uses transparent background for glare */    
  --col1: rgba(255,255,255, 0.80);
  --col2: rgba(255,255,255, 0.99);
  
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  var(--col1) 0%, var(--col2) 33%, var(--col1) 66%, var(--col2) 100%);
 
 /* background-color does nothing while gradient is up but this works for another tint: */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100vw rgba(0, 0, 150, 0.05);
  
  /* at same div level need this */
  z-index: 2;
}

.glossy3 {
  z-index: 2;

  /* blue tint */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100vw rgba(20, 20, 150, 0.09);

  /* uses transparent background for glare  */  
  --col1: rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
  --col2: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
  
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  var(--col1) 0%, var(--col2) 33%, var(--col1) 66%, var(--col2) 100%);
}


/* js adds on clipPath on top of this to crop it only under glossy3 */
.blurit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;  
  /* more supported filter */
  
  color: black;
  z-index: 1;  
  filter: blur(4px) brightness(1) contrast(1) saturate(0.9); 
  /* blocks other pre layer */
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);
}


@supports (backdrop-filter: blur(1px)) {
  .glossy {
    /* can put stuff here */
  }
}

@supports not (backdrop-filter: blur(1px)) {
  .glossy {
    /* can put stuff here */
  }
}

  
.irrelevant {
  /* irrelevant stuff */ 
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* includes padding in calculation */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  /* styling because why not */
  padding: calc(2 * (1vw + 1vh));
  font-size: calc(1.5 * (1vw + 1vh));
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2vw;
  width: 80%;
}

.irrelevant1 {
  top: 20%;
}

.irrelevant3 {
  top: 80%;
}

/* making background with text and random image so can see div effects better */ 
body, html {

  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(1 * (1vw + 1vh));
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;  
}

.background,
.background::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;  
  height: 100vh;
}

.background::before {
  content: ""; 
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/up3AMmC.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0.25;
  z-index: -2;
}

.background {
  overflow-y: scroll;  
}

pre {
  /* color: transparent; */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="glossy1 irrelevant1 irrelevant">
  backdrop-filter blur effect <br>
  for chrome and others<br>
  firefox not support by default yet (2020)
</div>

<div class="glossy2 irrelevant2 irrelevant">
  basic glare gradient only<br>
  even firefox can do
</div>

<div class="glossy3 irrelevant3 irrelevant">
  javascript with blur on cloned layer <br>
  + glare gradient<br>
  even firefox can do
</div>

<!-- background stuff -->
<div class="background">
  <pre style="white-space: pre-line; ">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris cursus dui eu lacus pretium malesuada. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas sit amet vestibulum quam. Suspendisse iaculis sed sem venenatis mattis. Vestibulum sed imperdiet justo. Nunc pharetra ante vitae ligula faucibus ullamcorper. Proin rutrum leo est, eu convallis arcu rutrum vel.

Duis congue enim quis mauris tincidunt ornare. Nullam vehicula diam vel erat ornare, et posuere enim dapibus. Vestibulum aliquam semper tortor, vel fringilla eros faucibus in. Suspendisse potenti. Nam aliquam mi nisl, eu porta eros auctor maximus. Proin tempus vestibulum nisi, a hendrerit quam varius a. Donec dui massa, rhoncus ut commodo non, eleifend vitae mauris. Nam pharetra lobortis magna eget pretium. Donec non gravida velit, et malesuada massa. Nullam iaculis, neque tincidunt cursus maximus, nisl ligula mattis felis, ac molestie lectus eros sed dolor. Nullam vel condimentum justo. Aliquam scelerisque eget metus non ornare.

In nulla tellus, consectetur vitae mattis sed, imperdiet luctus odio. Pellentesque metus dolor, maximus posuere rutrum et, condimentum quis erat. Donec rhoncus metus sit amet tortor lobortis tincidunt. Praesent arcu orci, fermentum auctor eros id, bibendum aliquam diam. Curabitur aliquet vel massa ac cursus. Mauris molestie convallis nisi, sit amet vestibulum turpis consectetur quis. Vivamus ut convallis enim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc quis lectus vitae turpis dictum elementum.

Nullam ultricies mi in rhoncus vestibulum. In ultrices convallis enim, ut pretium urna elementum nec. Cras quam leo, consequat non elit dapibus, ultricies consectetur est. Vivamus bibendum justo a felis rutrum tincidunt. Morbi sit amet nulla porttitor, tempus lacus eget, sollicitudin velit. Nunc non nulla turpis. Sed dictum dictum eros, sagittis fermentum felis pretium a. Etiam a nunc ante. Cras pharetra mi eros, a aliquam mi faucibus in.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus non aliquam leo. Fusce faucibus volutpat magna et tempor. Praesent in lorem a tortor pulvinar laoreet. Curabitur sit amet justo non massa aliquet pulvinar id vitae sem. Maecenas ullamcorper, felis sed volutpat aliquam, mauris odio pharetra diam, in vestibulum ante tellus vitae est. Suspendisse efficitur massa leo, non maximus risus molestie quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas tempus venenatis est vel sagittis. Fusce scelerisque mauris purus, a ornare est semper eget. Fusce commodo malesuada libero, imperdiet ullamcorper nibh rutrum quis. Donec quis ex eu diam varius pretium ut eget diam. Vivamus in interdum enim.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus non aliquam leo. Fusce faucibus volutpat magna et tempor. Praesent in lorem a tortor pulvinar laoreet. Curabitur sit amet justo non massa aliquet pulvinar id vitae sem. Maecenas ullamcorper, felis sed volutpat aliquam, mauris odio pharetra diam, in vestibulum ante tellus vitae est. Suspendisse efficitur massa leo, non maximus risus molestie quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas tempus venenatis est vel sagittis. Fusce scelerisque mauris purus, a ornare est semper eget. Fusce commodo malesuada libero, imperdiet ullamcorper nibh rutrum quis. Donec quis ex eu diam varius pretium ut eget diam. Vivamus in interdum enim.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus non aliquam leo. Fusce faucibus volutpat magna et tempor. Praesent in lorem a tortor pulvinar laoreet. Curabitur sit amet justo non massa aliquet pulvinar id vitae sem. Maecenas ullamcorper, felis sed volutpat aliquam, mauris odio pharetra diam, in vestibulum ante tellus vitae est. Suspendisse efficitur massa leo, non maximus risus molestie quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas tempus venenatis est vel sagittis. Fusce scelerisque mauris purus, a ornare est semper eget. Fusce commodo malesuada libero, imperdiet ullamcorper nibh rutrum quis. Donec quis ex eu diam varius pretium ut eget diam. Vivamus in interdum enim.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus non aliquam leo. Fusce faucibus volutpat magna et tempor. Praesent in lorem a tortor pulvinar laoreet. Curabitur sit amet justo non massa aliquet pulvinar id vitae sem. Maecenas ullamcorper, felis sed volutpat aliquam, mauris odio pharetra diam, in vestibulum ante tellus vitae est. Suspendisse efficitur massa leo, non maximus risus molestie quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas tempus venenatis est vel sagittis. Fusce scelerisque mauris purus, a ornare est semper eget. Fusce commodo malesuada libero, imperdiet ullamcorper nibh rutrum quis. Donec quis ex eu diam varius pretium ut eget diam. Vivamus in interdum enim.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus non aliquam leo. Fusce faucibus volutpat magna et tempor. Praesent in lorem a tortor pulvinar laoreet. Curabitur sit amet justo non massa aliquet pulvinar id vitae sem. Maecenas ullamcorper, felis sed volutpat aliquam, mauris odio pharetra diam, in vestibulum ante tellus vitae est. Suspendisse efficitur massa leo, non maximus risus molestie quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas tempus venenatis est vel sagittis. Fusce scelerisque mauris purus, a ornare est semper eget. Fusce commodo malesuada libero, imperdiet ullamcorper nibh rutrum quis. Donec quis ex eu diam varius pretium ut eget diam. Vivamus in interdum enim.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus non aliquam leo. Fusce faucibus volutpat magna et tempor. Praesent in lorem a tortor pulvinar laoreet. Curabitur sit amet justo non massa aliquet pulvinar id vitae sem. Maecenas ullamcorper, felis sed volutpat aliquam, mauris odio pharetra diam, in vestibulum ante tellus vitae est. Suspendisse efficitur massa leo, non maximus risus molestie quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas tempus venenatis est vel sagittis. Fusce scelerisque mauris purus, a ornare est semper eget. Fusce commodo malesuada libero, imperdiet ullamcorper nibh rutrum quis. Donec quis ex eu diam varius pretium ut eget diam. Vivamus in interdum enim.
  </pre>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8hkawmvo/6/