# How do I make <div>s wipe vertically onto each other when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, html, fixed

I have several `position:fixed;` divs. When I scroll down, I want the first div to appear to "wipe" over the second, and so on for several other divs.

How can I code this? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide code and demonstrate some attempt at doing this yourself already.

Comment: if the divs are moving, then they're not really fixed, are they?

Comment: @Tro - http://jsfiddle.net/YB9nV/ Currently, the divs stick when they reach the top of the page, becoming the new "low div" that the next div scrolls over. I want all divs to be static, but when scrolling, they "wipe" into each other.

Comment: @Stano, I mean that the divs don't actually visibly move -- but their visibility scrolls up. Like so: http://youtu.be/KjdQHr6_FT4 Thanks for fixing the jsfiddle. The code worked in Chrome for me originally...

Comment: Found something like this but dunno how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509492/how-to-make-a-div-with-glassy-and-semi-transparent-effect#5510832 And maybe this can be helpful if somebody knows how to make that transition: http://jsfiddle.net/YB9nV/3/  .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```html
<div class="divFixed">fixed</div>
<div class="divFlow">...lots of content</div>
```

```css
.divFixed {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.divFlow {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    background: yellow;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/qk5n8/)**

Comment: Hi, Apologies for my vagueness -- this isn't what I meant. Here's what I have already -- http://jsfiddle.net/YB9nV/ . I want both divs to be static, but wipe into each other, as if you're scrolling the z-index up.

Answer (score 0):

Your can compare initial element's top position value and current window's scrollTop position and change the position from fixed to absolute as needed:

```js
$(function () {
    var divs = $('#div1, #div2, #div3');
    divs.each(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-top', $(this).position().top);
    });
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        divs.each(function(){
            var datatop = $(this).attr('data-top');
            if (datatop > scrollTop) {
                this.style.position = 'absolute';
                this.style.top = datatop + 'px';
            } else {
                this.style.position = 'fixed';
                this.style.top = '0px';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QTHuL/5/